# One specific "socket.on()" doesn't work on client side

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Server receive message from socket.emit("Wiadomosc"), but client doesn't,
but when I emit message from server io.emit("Wiadomosc"), client receive message;

There is no errors, others socket.emit() socket.on() works fine
I tried everything: copied everything from working functions and nothing.
I think that there is something wrong with me and not with code

Okey, client side:

```
socket = io.connect("localhost:4000", {
        transports: ['websocket']
    });

    socket.on("Wiadomosc", function () {
        console.log("wd");
    });


    socket.on("gotowosc", function () {
        $(".gotowosc").css("display", "block");
    });

//somewhere else in code
console.log(socket) //to see if it's fine, and it is
socket.emit("Wiadomosc");
```

the second one works fine

server side:

```
let express = require("express");
let app = express();
let server = app.listen(4000, function () {
  console.log("listening on port 4000");
});
let socket = require("socket.io");
let io = socket(server);

io.on("connection", function (socket) {
  socket.on("Wiadomosc", function () { //I did something like that to check if emit works, and it works
    console.log("fine");
  });
});

io.emit("gotowosc");
```

Comment: If `socket.emit("Wiadomosc");` isn't received by the client, then it's probably because you aren't using the correct `socket` object on the server or don't have the right listener on the client.  We'd have to see a lot more of the code context (both client and server) to advise further.

Comment: Since it appears you may be new here, for questions like this, stackoverflow requires that you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  You need to post a bunch more code to provide that.

Comment: Okey, I think that's what is needed

Comment: Where's the code for `socket.emit()` both the one that works and the one that doesn't?  Are you saying that `console.log("fine")` is showing correctly, but `console.log("wd")` is not?

Comment: Also, is your web page loaded from the same server?  I ask because I don't see any express routes that would server your web page or the socket.io code.

Comment: Yes, everything is working correctly. I'm in a middle of writing game, and every other emit() and on() works. And yes, console.log("fine") works, and console.log("wd") doesn't

Comment: But I have one question. If I emit from client, every client should receive that, yes?
Because if not, that may be the problem. But if I remember correctly it should work

Comment: No.  emitting from a client sends to the server, not to any other client.  `io.emit()` from the server will send to every client that is currently connected to the default namespace.

Comment: Oooooooooooooooooo, sooooo, that's it. Well, my bad. Thanks, have a good day :D

Comment: Your `.emit()` code would not work as you show it because of timing.  We need to see REAL code to help.  For example, the server `io.emit()` would be sent when there were no connected clients.  The client-side `socket.emit()` would be sent before the client socket finished connecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emitting from a client sends to the server, not to any other client.  If you want to send a message from one client to all clients, you send a message to the server and then code the server to receive it and send it to other clients.